# Provide Pattern for Tesseract

Tags: tesseract

I'm using go and tesseract together. I have something like
2^3 or 22^55

And Tesseract is still sometimes wrong with a white list so I'm looking for a way to provide pattern I read through the FaQ and tried the suggested option with the bazaar.

My Pattern file looks like this:

```js
\d\d^\d\d
\d^\d\d
\d^\d
\d^\d\d
```

But somehow It still doesnt work. Are there any tips to get it working or is the only way to realize this to generate a new language file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a developer so forgive me.

I was looking into a similar issue a while ago and found that the description in the source code is confusing as tesseract by default needs 4+ constant characters in front of the pattern. It even provides examples that would not work under default conditions.

However this is configurable as is described in:
[The trie.h code](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/dict/trie.h?r=3c21c149492bda540eba991a6e102633c2d12318)

kSaneNumConcreteChars I am pretty sure was the parameter you are after.

Hope this helps.